# How do I remove duplicates and rejoin data when I'm removing duplicates based on different criteria independently?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm having issues wrapping my head around the removal of duplicates and properly rejoining data when there's duplicates all over the place.

My original dataset has:
`SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID, Customer_Name, Customer_Address1, Customer_Address2, Customer_City, Customer_State, Customer_Zip`

What I need to get to:
A dataset of unique customers from the original dataset with the same fields

Data relationships

- A CustomerID represents one unique customer.  John Kerry and Barack Obama will never have the same CustomerID.
- A CustomerID may have more than one Customer_Name and
  Customer_Address1.  Barack Obama will have the same CustomerID, but he may have two different rows, one with Barack Obama at the White House address and another at his prior home address.
- A Customer_Name and Customer_Address1 combination will sometimes be
  improperly associated with more than one CustomerID. Sometimes there's an error in data collection and Barack Obama at the White House will have 2 CustomerIDs, because they didn't look up their original account.
- Therefore I need to dedupe on both CustomerID and (Customer_Name,
  Customer_Address1) independently

Let's say I have 3 records with the following values for 3 fields:

```
CustomerID; Customer_Name, Customer_Address1
100; Barack Obama; 1600 Pennsylvania
101; Barack Obama; 1600 Pennsylvania
100; Barack Obama; 100 Imaginary Address
```

Using these 3 fields, I need to turn these 3 rows into one row. Does not matter which of the 3 rows, but for the selected row, I need to rejoin or carry forward all of the additional address information.

Comment: If a name/address combo has more than one ID, which one do you want?

Comment: I don't think it will matter which one in this specific problem.

Comment: Do you have any primary keys? What is the actual data structure (e.g. what table(/s) are storing the Name/Address fields), If this is a flat table structure how would you know which record would require deleting (e.g. if `Customer_Name` "Jane Jones" and "Jane Smith" were both assigned to `customerID` 123). It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do; it might be that you should look at deleting according to the comparison with an aggregate function (e.g. `primary_key_column_name = MIN(primary_key_column_name) AND COUNT(*) > 1` ) should an appropriate one exist.

Comment: I added an example at the problem that tries to more explicitly explain what my data looks like in terms of the source and destination.  Hopefully this helps, if not, let me know.

Comment: So, for Barack Obama you want to end up with one row with some semi-random version of the other fields?  Try `SELECT Customer_Name,max(customer_id),max(...) from <yourtable> GROUP BY Customer_Name`.

Comment: I'll be testing the SQL syntax in a few hours and then I'll return with results!